# POST request as URL string?

Tags: rest, post, oauth-2.0, google-api

I have an application that can do `POST` and `GET` requests if I pass them as a String.

I'm trying to hit some Google APIs and am getting stuck trying to make the `refresh_token` `POST` request.

The format that google wants is:

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id={client_id}&
client_secret={client_secret}&
refresh_token=1/6BMfW9j53gdGImsiyUH5kU5RsR4zwI9lUVX-tqf8JXQ&
grant_type=refresh_token
```

My question is can I make this POST request as a string if the `client_id`, `client_secret`, `refresh_token` are URLencoded?

Like this:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_id={client_id}&client_secret={secret}&refresh_token=1%26BMfW9j53gdGImsiyUH5kU5RsR4zwI9lUVX-tqf8JXQ&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Comment: Your example isn't "URL encoding", it's simply passing the information in a `GET` request. If `/o/oauth2/token` supports `GET`, then yes, this will work. If it only supports `POST`, this will not work.

Comment: By URLencoding I mean that I manually URLencode it. In my application I have it toggled to POST but I have no idea what it is doing underneath.

Comment: What do you mean by `manually URLencode it`?

Comment: I mean the process of changing spaces to %20. I had read that the '/' in the refresh token needed to be encoded. http://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Comment: Again, if `/o/oauth2/token` supports `GET`, then this will work. If it doesn't, then it won't.